# What kind of Ruby data structure is this?

Tags: ruby, data-structures

A very simple question, but I'm new to Ruby and not able to determine the name of this type of data structure:

```
location = 145.6, 56.644
```

I searched for point, pair, comma-seperated value etc. but was not successful. Could you tell me what this is?

Thank you

Comment: Explore these examples: `a,b = 1,2`; `a,b = 1,2,3`; `a,*b = 1,2,3`; `*a,b = 1,2,3`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[This is an array , see more examples here](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html)

Comment: oh, this was easy.. thank you. Never thought of an array due to the missing brackets.

Comment: Your welcome, often you will find multiple ways to do similar things in ruby.

Answer (score 3):

You can call the class method to find out

```
location.class
```

=> Array

Answer (score -1):

It is just array. In ruby you can drop out brackets in some cases:

```
drakmail@thinkpad-x220:~$ irb
irb(main):001:0> def test_me(a,b)
irb(main):002:1> print "a is #{a} and b is #{b}"
irb(main):003:1> end
=> nil
irb(main):004:0> test_me 5,10
a is 5 and b is 10=> nil
```

Comment: -1 Optional brackets in calling a method is quite different from the syntax sugar for an automatic splat during multiple assignment to a single variable.